# My C# code printing random numbers instead of the sum

Tags: c#, .net, console

I am new to C# and was trying to solve the following problem:

> Write a program in C# to find the sum of all elements of the array. Go to the editor
> Test Data:
>
> ```
> Input the number of elements to be stored in the array: 3
> Input 3 elements in the array:
> element - 0: 2
> element - 1: 5
> element - 2: 8
> ```
>
> Expected Output:
>
> ```
> Sum of all elements stored in the array is: 15
> ```

Here is the solution I came up with:

```cs
Console.Write("Enter the length of the array : ");
int len = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = new int[len];
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
}
Console.WriteLine(arr.Sum());
```

But I am getting the following outputs:
[image: 1]

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tochar?view=net-8.0#system-convert-tochar(system-int32)

Comment: First of all, your use of `Console.Read()` is incorrect, as `Read()` only reads a **single** character, which means that if you attempt to insert `10` as a value, you're actually going to be inserting `1`.

Comment: @akseli not `1` but `(int)'1'` which is `49`.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, sorry! My bad!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing `Console.Read` to `Console.ReadLine` and using `int.Parse` directly:

```cs
for (int ii = 0; ii < len; ii++) {
    arr[ii] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

And then enter numbers on different lines (note that usually `int.TryParse` is recommended to use to validate the input, because `int.Parse` will throw if string can't be parsed into a number).

[`Console.Read`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.read?view=net-8.0) already returns an `int` which is:

> The next character from the input stream, or negative one (-1) if there are currently no more characters to be read.

Which represents encoded character (including spaces, letters, etc.) value. I.e. if you enter `1` you will get `49` as the result (try for example `Console.WriteLine((int)'1')`).

Comment: Thanks its works now, but can you please explain to me why my solution wasn't working? Live I have been using the Convert.ToInt32() and never have I got any error.

Comment: @SagnikMajumder was glad to help! If answer works for you do not forget to mark it as accepted one. As for why - check the `Console.Read`  remark. `Convert.ToInt32` is not the issue here, it is basically no-op because `Console.Read` returns int.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the `131` result, remember the input is a string `1 2 3`. **This includes the spaces.** The `Console.Read()` function returns an **int** value for each character, *including spaces*.

So what you're seeing is the sum of **the ascii<sup>*</sup> int values** of the first three characters in that string: `1` (49), `2` (50), and the space character between them (32), which gives you 131 as the result.

---

<sub>* C# actually uses unicode, but the Windows (or other) console may be using something different. For this example, however, they'll all be ascii-compatible.</sub>